# Problems with websockets, NginX and the AWS load balancer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I have a Node.js server running socket.io. I would like to connect to this server from a web-page served by another Node.js server. For both servers I am using the AWS classic load-balancer with SSL turned on. My certificates are Amazon issued ones.

I managed to get it working using the polling transport, but I would like use websockets for performance reasons. However, as far as I understand it, the default NginX config for Elastic Beanstalk does not support the connection upgrade.

Based on some [guides](http://dustinbolton.com/websockets-not-working-on-elastic-beanstalk-with-nodejs-when-using-nginx-as-a-proxy/) I have tried the following:

I have added this to `.ebextensions/01_websockets_nginx.config`:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websocketupgrade.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

I have my load balancer configured as follows:

```
Load Balancer Protocol    Load Balancer Port    Instance Protocol     Instance Port

HTTP                      80                    HTTP                  80
HTTPS                     443                   HTTP                  80
```

But when I access my client web-page, I get this message in my browser console:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://.../socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=zNi1IqNWHYo3WwjgAAAB.

I have tried various different configurations with no success. What is the secret recipe for getting this to work?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think I left a clear and detailed question.

Comment: Why are you using the classic/legacy ELB and not the new ALB (which should support web sockets) ? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

Comment: At the time of asking the new ALB did not support web sockets.